# Load The Pages From The PDF File One By One

Tags: pdf

I have a **PDF file**(E book) with 19 MB contain **52 pages**. I have already inserted and display the PDF file in my web page.

```
<embed src="file_name.pdf" width="800px" height="2100px" />
```

When i load my web page, its loading whole PDF File (19 MB). Its taking too much time to load.

I want to load the first page only while load the website. After visitor click the 2nd page, the 2nd page needs to download and visible to the visitor.

May i know its possible? or any-other method available for my need.

Thank You!

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You need to meet the following three requirements though.

1. PDF file needs to be saved in `Linearized` mode (also known as "Fast Web View").
2. The web server hosting the PDF file must support [HTTP range request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) headers.
3. The user must be using a PDF viewer that supports reading Linearized PDF files.

If (1) is not true, then you need a tool/library that can convert non-linearized PDF files to linearized.

As for (3) unless you control what viewer the user uses, then this is out of your control.  For example, at least on Windows 10, Firefox, Chrome and new Chromium Edge all support reading Linearized PDF files.

Comment: Thank You bro. i will try it.